# Looping a certain number of times in tapestry template

Tags: tapestry

In a Tapestry component template, is there a simple way to render some markup X times, where X is a parameter of the component?

All I can find in the Tapestry docs is the Loop component:

```html
<table class="navigation" xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_0_0.xsd">
    <tr>
        <t:loop source="pageNames" value="pageName">
            <td class="${tabClass}">
                <t:pagelink page="pageName">${pageName}</t:pagelink>
            </td>
        </t:loop>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But this is overkill if I just want to render something X times, without needing to pass any parameters. For this usecase I'd really expect something like (pseudo-code):

```html
<table class="navigation" xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_0_0.xsd">
    <tr>
        <t:loop times="${x}">
            <!-- same markup every time -->
        </t:loop>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But nothing like this seems to exist - or does it?

For now my workaround is to provide a stub implementation of List which gives size X, and use that as my Loop source:

Class:

```java
private int x;

public List<Object> getX() {
    return new AbstractList<Object>() {
        public Object get(int arg0) {
            return null;
        }
        public int size() {
            return x;
        }
    };
}
```

Template:

```html
<t:loop source="x">
    <!-- same markup each time -->
</t:loop>
```

But this is very ugly - surely there's a nicer way to do something so straightforward?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with a loop and tapestry's range operator

```html
Santa Claus said: <t:loop t:source="1..3">Ho</t:loop>
```

http://tapestry.apache.org/property-expressions.html

Comment: Changed this to the accepted answer as I was looking for exactly such a baked-in way to achieve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Repeating static content in a template isn't very common in my world.  If it is in yours, then writing your own component is in order.

Here's my solution: https://gist.github.com/4402251

Drop it in your component package and use it like:

```xml
 <t:repeat times="100">.</t:repeat>
 <t:repeat times="5" element="p">
     This is repeated 5 times...
 </t:repeat>

 <ul>
     <li t:type="repeat" times="3">Repeated 3 times</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the component code, exactly what I needed. Admittedly a fairly uncommon requirement, but still a very rudimentary one so I'm surprised Tapestry doesn't provide this out of the box - assumed I must be missing something obvious in the docs!